# Limiting Scope Powershell

Tags: powershell

So i've been playing around with this script to audit file server folder ACL's, and it works great, just returning too much data.  What i was hoping i could do is filter out the folders where there are no special permissions than the parent folder, I think this would help me reduce the amount of entries into my table and allow me to manipulate it into something more readable. Basically only return the parent ACL and any child object that doesn't inherit from parent or has special permissions.

```
 $connectionString = "Server=KCC-RPT-Admin\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Audit;User ID=report_admin; Password=Payday!5;"
$tableName = "FilePermissions"

function WriteSQL ($query)
{
    if ($debug -eq $true) {Write-Host $query}
    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $Connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
    $Connection.Open()
    $Command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $command.Connection = $Connection
    $command.CommandText = $query
    $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $connection.Close()
}

$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue" 
$strComputer = $env:ComputerName 
$colDrives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider Filesystem 
ForEach ($DriveLetter in $colDrives) { 
    $StartPath = "E:\Share\" 
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $StartPath -Recurse -Directory | 
    ForEach { 
      $FullPath = Get-Item -LiteralPath (Get-Item -LiteralPath $_.PSPath) 
      (Get-Item -LiteralPath $FullPath).GetAccessControl() | 
      Select * -Expand Access | 
      Select @{N='ServerName';E={$strComputer}}, 
             @{N='FullPath';E={$FullPath}}, 
             @{N='Type';E={If($FullPath.PSIsContainer -eq $True) {'D'} Else {'F'}}}, 
             @{N='Owner';E={$_.Owner}}, 
             @{N='Trustee';E={$_.IdentityReference}}, 
             @{N='Inherited';E={$_.IsInherited}}, 
             @{N='InheritanceFlags';E={$_.InheritanceFlags}}, 
             @{N='AceFlag';E={$_.PropagationFlags}}, 
             @{N='AceType';E={$_.AccessControlType}}, 
             @{N='AccessMasks';E={$_.FileSystemRights}} } |

             %{
                $query = "INSERT INTO $tableName (servername,fullpath,type,owner,trustee,inherited,inheritanceflags,aceflag,acetype,accessmasks) VALUES ('$($_.servername)','$($_.fullpath)','$($_.type)','$($_.owner)','$($_.trustee)','$($_.inherited)','$($_.inheritanceflags)','$($_.aceflag)','$($_.acetype)','$($_.accessmasks)')"
                WriteSQL $query
             }

    }
```

Comment: Do you know [SysInternals' AccessEnum](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/accessenum.aspx) already does this? Including only displaying directories if the permissions differ from the parent, and files if the permissions are more open than the parent folder?

Comment: it doesn't do it well, it looks like it returns ACL's for every single file

Comment: `Options -> File Permissions Options -> Display files with permissions that differ from parent` ? (Although that sounds like it will display *more* files. Are you sure all your files don't have less restrictive permissions somehow?)